# Make an asp .net web app offline

Tags: asp.net

Basically a web app that we distribute to clients, one of whom will be trialling it so I need to be able to switch it off at a certain point.  Don't want to put the end date in the web.config in case they work out they can change it, I was thinking of putting something in the global.asax with a hard coded date, but then I'm not sure how I can 'turn off' the app.  I was thinking of checking the date in the Authenticate Request part and simply redirecting to a page that says your trial is finished (or something similar), but is there a better way?

Comment: You mean to say, you will not be hosting it & your clients will host the code themselves?

Comment: the app is installed on the clients server

Comment: If you try to make the `app_offline.html` then the user can remove permissions to make files there, so they can avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that on `global.asax` as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(DateTime.UtcNow > cTheTimeLimitDate)
   {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("...message to show...");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return ;    
   }    
}
```

this is safer than place it on web.config, but nothing is safe enough. Its even better there to redirect them to a page, or not show them a message, or what ever you think.

For make redirect to a page you also need to check if the call if for a page, and the code will be as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
   string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);
   if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
   {
     // and here is the time limit.
     if(DateTime.UtcNow > cTheTimeLimitDate)
     {
        // make here the redirect
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return ;    
    }    
  }
}
```

To makes it even harder, you can make a custom BasePage that all page come from it (and not from `System.Web.UI.Page`) and you place there the limit on the render of the page - or show a message on top of every page render, that the time is ends.

```
public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)        
    {
        if(DateTime.UtcNow > cTheTimeLimitDate)
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

            // render page inside the buffer
            base.Render(htmlWriter);

            string html = stringWriter.ToString();

            writer.Write("<h1>This evaluation is expired</h1><br><br>" + html);         
        }
        else
        {
            base.Render(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the app_offline.htm and you can even create a nice message for your users. Also it's very easy to put the site back online, just remove or rename the app_offline.htm.

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/09/24/take-an-asp-net-application-offline.aspx

Comment: He wants to give the users a trial kind of application. This will not workout for him as any ASP.NET developer should know removing the app_offline.htm will get back the site online.